# How to create a folder which listens for changed files or new files

Tags: windows, service, extract

I have a requirement where I create many swc files (swc files are similar to zip or jar files). I want that, whenever I create a new swc file and add it in a "particular folder" then these files should automatically get extracted (similar to what happens in Apache Tomcat webapps folder). Please help me how to do that in Windows. 
[Note: I know I can write a ant/rake/gradle script which can do this for me, but just to explore more in Windows how to achieve this]

Answer (score 3):

Use the FileSystemWatcher class if you're using .NET. ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6165137.html))

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using .NET, then you can use the [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx) function to listen for filesystem changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a windows scripted fashion, you would use a WMI Event Watcher. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141130.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you could use the .NET FileSystemWatcher to do this task.  (from withing c#, vb.net, etc..)
with FileSystemWatcher you can observer creation, deletion and modification of files and react to those events.

Answer (score 0):

FileSystemWatcher is the obvious choice in .Net.

IMHO, its not a good component. Many a times it raises double events for change of files and I have not been able to do a neat implementation using FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use .NET (for kids)
Use Win32 api notifications (8 lines of code)

Comment: .Net is for kids? You obviously need to wring your brain out: it's full of dirty water.

Comment: Btw, it is 0 lines of code in .Net if you use the Forms designer.